# No Windows 7 users available for login after Dell DataSafe factory reset

Tags: windows-7, dell-inspiron

I created install discs using the Dell DataSafe 2.0 backup utility in order to re-install Windows on a friend's laptop (Dell Inspiron N5110). I ran the discs to do a factory reset.

After the whole process, it booted, started loading Windows 7, displayed the messages "setup is preparing your computer for first use" and "setup is checking video performance," and showed the login screen.

However, there don't seem to be any active users on the machine—I opened a command prompt window to check the users on the machine.

Using the command prompt (again, from the login window), I activated/enabled the administrator account, and even created another admin account, and upon logging in received several errors, couldn't load any MMCs, etc.

Comment: It sounds as though the installation failed. You may be able to do a repair, but I'd try reinstalling again, since you have nothing to lose.

Comment: yeah, it seems like it, but i didn't get any error messages during the "reset." I've tried several times (different variations) and no luck.

Comment: Have you tried "administrator" with a blank password?

Comment: @harrymc yeah :(  i tried every "default" combination i could think of.

Comment: @CharlieRB unfortunately, after arguing with a Dell Support tech and their supervisor (for about an hour) about how it wasn't a Windows issue and that it was caused by the Dell datasafe backup install, they wanted me to pay ~$200 for some plan i didn't need/want, so I ended up ordering a windows 7 disk for about $20 through the dell site and did a fresh windows install. Sorry i couldn't report any good news, but i'm interested to see if anyone has had better luck.

Comment: Had the same argument with them and had the same offer to buy a software warranty then they would send a fix CD. I laughed at them and suggested Dell was ignoring the issue as several instances were posted in there forums. They promptly put me on hold to be transferred to the warranty department. During the wait I was disconnected.

Comment: @user897052 Can you please provide the link on where to buy this $20 CD on the Dell site? I've searched a lot and couldn't find it. I'm guessing fro this price they don't provide a new windows serial number and you have to reuse the one on that came with your laptop

Comment: @ruda.almeida - I suggest you contact dell directly.

Comment: I'm not a Dell customer, I just to make my answer more complete.

Comment: @ruda.almeida I believe I ordered it from [here](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dellcare/en/backupcd_form)

Comment: I have Dell Studio 15 Direct Base laptop and I have tried once with Dell DataSafe Backup utility. I took backup of my machine and then I did a restore on the same machine. All went fine and I didn't faced any issues with that. I think, if we create install-disks from one configuration of Dell and try to restore in another configuration or another Dell machine, then some additional steps may be required to fix the encountered problems, like booting the machine with knoppix or any other bootable medium, doing a repair of Windows 7 with the original CD and other things as and when found.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have nothing to lose, we can try 2 things. I hope you have some experience with Linux.

**1st method**

1. Download Knoppix from knoppix.net, burn it to cd and boot up your laptop
2. It should load up graphical interface by default
3. Look on desktop for your hard drive icon/folder, open it with read/write permission.
4. Look for the Administrator user folder, deleted it completely
5. Reboot into Windows 7 and try login administrator. Windows should rebuild a clean administrator directory

**2nd method**

1. Use gpart in knoppix or partition magic or similar partitioning software
2. delete windows ntfs partition, re-create it
3. Boot into Dell restor and rebuild the system

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to verify your suggestions, but I believe your 1st method may have been feasible solution and could have allowed the system to move forward with Windows Setup. Therefore, since it was the only one which met the criteria, I am awarding you the bounty. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments from users **CharlieRB** and **user897052** (actual question's OP), it is evident the less consuming and troublesome option is to [order a backup disc](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dellcare/en/backupcd_form) and perform a fresh install. Note: The OP reports being charged $20 for the disc with the OS).

(From the Dell site: `Dell Customers can now request a set of backup discs containing the factory-installed operating system as well as the device drivers and utilities specific to your system. Requests are limited to one (1) set of backup discs per system purchased. The backup discs requested must match the operating system that was factory installed on the original order.`)

During install, dont't forget to use the same Windows serial number from the label located on the backside of the laptop.

- If there is any data on the HDD then before reinstalling Windows, it is advised using a Linux LiveCD to backup all your data, such as suggested by user John Siu. I recommend [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (it can be [booted from a flashdrive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) as well). Then boot from Ubuntu and save all your data on a blank USB stick, for example.